# PHP Code with array

Tags: php

I have some code that shows a combobox. It's existing code. I need this combobox filled with a predefined array. I can't get this to work. Can someone help? This is the code

I can see the combobox but it is not filled with the array. I can see the array as printed text in the webpage above the combobox.

```
$array1 = array('One','Two','Three','Four','Five','Six','Seven','Eight');
print"<tr>". NEWLINE;
print"<td class='form-lbl-r'>". $translate->_('Release Name') ." <span class='required'>*</span></td>". NEWLINE;
print"<td class='form-data-l'><Select Name='Release' maxlength='20' name='rel_name_required' value='". session_validate_form_get_field("rel_name_required"). "'></td>". NEWLINE;
    foreach($array1 as $Released){ 
    print'<option value="'.$Released.'">'.$Released.'</option>'; 
} 
print'</select>';
print"</tr>". NEWLINE;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "see the array as printed text"?  What exactly do you see?  Are you sure this PHP code is even running?

Comment: don't close </TD> in between select tags.............

Comment: Working perfect. What is the problem ?

Comment: Hi, It's existing code and it was a inputfield=text and working fine. Now I want this existing code to be a combobox.

Comment: Web server says syntax error, unexpected foreach

Comment: What is that .newline , what should it do?

Answer (score 1):

By me the code work perfect...

```
<?php
$array1 = array('One','Two','Three','Four','Five','Six','Seven','Eight');
print"<tr>";
print"<td class='form-data-l'><select Name='Release' maxlength='20' name='rel_name_required' value='foobar'></td>";
    foreach($array1 as $Released){ 
    print'<option value="'.$Released.'">'.$Released.'</option>'; 
} 
print'</select>';
print"</tr>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try with:

```
$array1 = array('One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight');

echo '<tr>';
echo '<td class="form-lbl-r">' . $translate->_('Release Name') . ' <span class="required">*</span></td>';
echo '<td class="form-data-l">';
  echo '<select name="Release" maxlength="20" name="rel_name_required" value="' . session_validate_form_get_field('rel_name_required') . '">';
  foreach ($array1 as $Released) {
    echo '<option value="' . $Released . '">' . $Released . '</option>';
  }
  echo '</select>';
echo '</td>';
echo '</tr>';
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<select>` needs to be immediately followed by the `<option>`. Your code has a `</td>` at the end of that line.

Answer (score 0):

This is the proper way and working perfect :

```
   $array1 = array('One','Two','Three','Four','Five','Six','Seven','Eight');
    print "<tr>";
     print "<td class='form-lbl-r'>". $translate->_('Release Name') ." <span class='required'>*</span>";
        print "<td class='form-data-l'>";
                print "<Select Name='Release' maxlength='20' name='rel_name_required' value='". session_validate_form_get_field("rel_name_required"). "'>";
                    foreach($array1 as $Released){ 
                        print'<option value="'.$Released.'">'.$Released.'</option>'; 
                    } 
                print "</select>";
        print "</td>";
     print "</td>";
    print "</tr>";
```